# Пишу календарь событий с dhtmlxScheduler но в консоли выдает Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. помогите разобраться в чем дело

Tags: javascript, html5

```js
var events = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "Dentist",
    start_date: "08/11/2015 14:00",
    end_date: "08/11/2015 15:00"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Conference",
    start_date: "08/12/2015 12:00",
    end_date: "08/12/2015 19:00"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Kayaking",
    start_date: "08/15/2015 09:00",
    end_date: "08/16/2015 22:00"
  }
];


CREATE DATABASE schedule;
USE schedule;
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id`
  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_date`
  datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date`
  datetime NOT NULL,
  `text`
  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

scheduler.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";

/* loading data from the server */
scheduler.load("data.php");
/* saving data */
var dp = new dataProcessor("data.php");
dp.init(scheduler);

scheduler.parse(events, "json");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.calendar {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
    <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
      <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_header"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А где Вы видели в JS такой синтаксис: `CREATE DATABASE schedule;`?

Comment: @Yaant я нашел шаблон и пытаюсь разобраться как он работает и немного переделать его. Я не знаком с этим языком. Я новичок в js,что очевидно раз обращаюсь с такими вопросами, так что был бы благодарен что бы Вы оставляли конструктивные комментарии а не просто глумление типа где такой синтаксис видел.

Comment: Приведенный код между строчками `CREATE DATABASE schedule;` и 
`);` включительно не является JavaScript-кодом, поэтому и вызывает синтаксическую ошибку интерпретатора. Не знаю, куда уж конструктивнее.

Comment: @Yaant спибо за внимание-) Так а к чему же тот кусок кода в примере вообще вставлен?

Comment: Это вопрос к тому, кто его вставлял. Это SQL-код создания базы данных и таблицы. Можно предположить, что их каким-то образом использует этот самый scheduler.